# Cannot make logo to show up on html page(<img> tag) using VelocityEngine

Tags: java, image, velocity

Cannot embed static image link(AWS link to my-logo.png) in java VelocityEngine.

In java code:

```
velocityContext.put("esc", new EscapeTool());
```

And in .vm file:

```
<img src="$esc.url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.myproject.com/project-static/logos/my-logo.png')" alt="PR logo">
```

I'm getting a rendering error. I am able to see the link if I wrap it with some other html tag like `<p> or <h2>`, but when I put it inside `<img src="...">` in order to see the logo itself and not the url to it, then the page cannot be rendered and I see the following standard error: This site can’t be reachedThe webpage at http://localhost:8080/... might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE").
Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

The `esc.url` function internally uses `URLEncoder.encode` which is usually meant for encoding the query string part of the URL. Your URL, `https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.myproject.com/project-static/logos/my-logo.png`, doesn't have a query string and hence doesn't need encoding. `$esc.url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.myproject.com/project-static/logos/my-logo.png')` would return something like `https%3A%2F%2Fs3.amazonaws.com%2Fstatic.myproject.com%2Fproject-static%2Flogos%2Fmy-logo.png` which is not a valid URL and hence the error you are seeing. You should either remove the escaping entirely, escape only the query string part or escape only specific parts of the query string where characters not allowed in a URL are expected. Something like the below:

```
<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.myproject.com/project-static/logos/my-logo.png?label=$esc.url('small size')" alt="PR logo">
```